# Using ui-tinymce Directive in Another Directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tinymce

I'm trying to use the [ui-tinymce](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-tinymce) directive inside of another directive:

```
angular.module("risevision.widget.common.font-setting", ["ui.tinymce"])
  .directive("fontSetting", ["$templateCache", function ($templateCache) {
    return {
      restrict: "AE",
      template: $templateCache.get("_angular/font-setting/font-setting.html"),
      transclude: false,
      link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        $scope.tinymceOptions = {
          menubar: false,
          statusbar: false
        };
      }
    };
  }]);
```

And `_angular/font-setting/font-setting.html`:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="tinymceModel"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

The TinyMCE editor shows up, but it's ignoring the configuration options I've set in `$scope.tinymceOptions`. That is, the menu bar and status bar still show.

Any thoughts as to why it's not working?

Thx.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late to the party but I'm going to answer you in case someone has the same issue and can't find the answer.

TinyMce needs to be loaded only when the tinymceOptions variable has data so you need to wrap it in an ng-if:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" ng-if="tinymceOptions">
    <textarea ui-tinymce="$parent.tinymceOptions" ng-model="$parent.tinymceModel"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can avoid using $parent (elements inside ng-if have their own scope) using controller as inside the directive if you are using Angular >1.4:

```
app.directive('someDirective', function () {
  return {
    scope: {},
    bindToController: {
      someObject: '=',
      ...
    },
    controllerAs: 'ctrl',
    controller: function () {
      var ctrl = this;
      ctrl.message = 'Object loaded.';
    },
    template: '<div ng-if="ctrl.someObject">{{ctrl.message}}</div>'
  };
});
```